# Scipy imresize nearest neighbour gives incorrect results when downsampling

Tags: numpy, image-processing, scipy, interpolation, nearest-neighbor

I'm using the following code to resize the label images of semantic segmentation task [PASCAL VOC] ( images with values in range 0 to `n_classes` with `n_classes` = 21).

```
    lbl = m.imread(lbl_path)
    lbl = np.array(lbl, dtype=np.int32)
    lbl = self.encode_segmap(lbl)
    print 'Unique: ', np.unique(lbl), lbl.dtype
    plt.imshow(lbl)
    plt.show()
    lbl = m.imresize(lbl, (self.img_size, self.img_size), 'nearest')
    print 'Unique after resize: ', np.unique(lbl), lbl.dtype
    plt.imshow(lbl)
    plt.show()
```

When I run this, I get this output:

```
Unique: [ 0  1 15] int64
Unique after resize: [ 0  17 255] uint8
```

Shouldn't the values after resize ( using `nearest`) only belong to the set ( 0, 1, 15 )?

The images I get as output are :

Original
[image: original]

Resized
[image: resized]

Comment: What's the dtype before and after?  In binary the values are (000, 001, 111), (00000000, 00001001, 11111111)

Comment: Made changes to reflect the dtypes before and after.